# Retrieve Static Property Value From Class Name

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a static property that I need to access by name without instantiating the class.

THIS WORKS:

```
var importantVar = MyClass.MyStaticProperty;
```

THIS DOESN"T WORKS

```
var qualifiedName = "MyObjects.MyClass";
var theType = Type.GetType(qualifiedName);
var importantVar = (theType).MyStaticProperty;
```

theType returns null? How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is qualifiedName being set as a string value? theType would then be set as a type of string then your third variable would return null as there is no such concept of (string).MyStaticProperty. What's the issue with the first line anyway? Why not use that if it works?

Comment: @JJ173 That's how you retrieve `Type` from a string. The code is not incorrect.

Comment: @TanveerBadar okay cool, thanks for the clarification, just wanted to get a better understanding of what was being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (with your help):

```
var qualifiedName = "MyObjects.MyClass, MyObjects";
var theType = Type.GetType(qualifiedName);
var importantVar = theType.GetProperty("MyStaticProperty").GetValue(null);
```

Comment: What if property is a string array? I can get string value this way, but can't get if it is string array. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection. Do it like this

```
var importantVar = theType.GetProperty("MyStaticProperty", BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
```

Your value is typed as object, it is not evident from question what to cast it to.

Comment: Yeah, that looks right but "theType" is coming up null.

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question, because it could have any number of reasons.